# Black screen while installing Ubuntu 12.04.3 on Dell Precision M4800

Tags: 12.04, installation, dell

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS on my new Dell Precision M4800 (from a USB key, made from Ubuntu) and I've got that problem : after choosing my language on the boot screen, I can see no more things on my screen, it keeps black...

The graphic card is an NVidia Quadro K2100M...

I tried to boot with an Ubuntu 12.04.1 install USB key, and I had something on the screen but my ethernet card wasn't detected (the wifi was OK)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally have been able to correctly boot my USB key with option "nomodeset" at boot time and managed to install Ubuntu 12.04.3

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, on the same machine (Dell Precision 4800). I tried installing it from DVD and also from USB but end up with the same result. I disabled the media card and also USB3 - which was suggested in another thread but it does not solve the problem. Now I would like to try your solution. How does one boot a USB with option "nomodeset" at boot time? Could you please briefly explain what exactly you did and when? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It also works with 12.10 and "nomodeset"
From there  it is possible to update to trusty.

I didn't manage to install 13.04 directly since after 
installing and rebooting the system got lost in upstart madness.

However: In 12.10 and current 13.04 with nvidia-331, whenever the 
screen blanks, it is not possible to get the system to un-blank it again.

If you install sshd and log in from another machine the system 
proves to be working fine otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the procedure that I used, it works fine (enjoy the QHD+ screen !!!)

(skip steps 1-5 if you do not have a SSD)

1 (for SSDs) Use the Debian disk just to boot the system and obtain a shell (I do not remember the exact option)

2 (for SSDs) I created a big partition in the whole disk, starting at block 4096 (default).

3 (for SSDs) I could not find the information on erase block size for the LITEONIT SSD anywhere,so I'm using the default parameters ( `hdparm -I /dev/sda` reports model type, i.e. LITEONIT LCS-256M6S 2.5 7mm 256GB but I did not find erase block size information on the internet for this model)

4 (for SSDs) Create the filesystem: `mkfs.ext4 -b 4096 /dev/sda1`

5 (for SSDs) Restart installation, select manual partitioning, edit partition, set use as `ext4` , mount point: `/` , additional flags: `discard, noatime`
these flags are useful for SSDs, discard uses block erase capabilities of SSDs, and noatime prevents the system for recording last access time in every files.

6) First boot: edit booting options (using advanced mode from GRUB screen, select kernel, press <kbd>e</kbd>, remove load_video and add flags: `nomodeset text`, then press <kbd>F10</kbd>. `nomodeset` means that the console remains in text mode, and `text` means that the system will not attempt to start X11 graphics mode (it seems that the shipped drivers cannot drive the ultra HD screen)

7) edit `/etc/default/grub` , find the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"` and replace it with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet nomodeset"`

8) add `blacklist nouveau` in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` (create the file if it does not exist)

9) `update-grub`

10) `rmmod nouveau`

11) `aptitude install build-essential linux-headers-amd64 linux-headers-amd64-all`

12) Install NVIDIA driver (load it from NVIDIA's website)

13) `dpkg-reconfigure linux-image-3.13-1-amd64` (this re-creates the ramdisk that contains the device drivers, including the new NVidia driver, and re-initializes the grub boot loader). Note: use `uname -a` to see the version of your kernel (and replace in `dpkg-reconfigure` command accordingly)

14) restart the system: `shutdown -r`
Normally, it will boot in graphics mode (and you will see tiny tiny icons, there are far too many pixels in this screen !!)

15) To make screen contrast hotkey work:
  edit `etc/default/grub` , find the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet nomodeset"
```

and replace it with

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet acpi_osi=\"!Windows 2012\" acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

then do:

```
update_grub
```

Just one thing that does not work: switching to text mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> gives me a black screen, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> gives me graphics back. Same thing when the screen-saver blanks the screen (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> gives me the screen back).

Comment: Bruno, Thanks, that's very helpful. I am considering the M4800 for my work laptop but I cannot decide between AMD/ATI and NVIDIA graphics card. My desired setup is to use E-Port Plus dock and have two external screens attached. Laptop screen won't be used while docked. I see you chose the NVIDIA option. Are you having any troubles? (besides those you fixed by nomodeset). My current laptop is XPS15 with the Intel / Nvidia optimus combo. So far I haven't been able to use my external screen (HDMI) from Linux. And I'd hate to get trapped again.. Thank you!